# Detach a notebook programmatically

Tags: databricks

Is it possible to detach a notebook from a cluster programmatically? Maybe using the databricks API or CLI or other SDK?

Context: Some notebooks stay idle for hours on our shared clusters. Users often close them without detaching or freeing up memory. Also, the cluster rarely terminates because someone is always using it. I would like to see if that can be optimized

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a setting to control the auto-eviction / detachment behavior currently. However, A simple fix as a platform administrator is to decrease your auto-termination timeout setting. It doesn't matter if a notebook is attached, the moment the notebooks becomes "Idle" state is when the clock starts ticking for your cluster auto-termination.

So, if your auto-termination is say 2 hours currently, try lowering that to something more reasonable like 30 minutes.

Also, as a user, in the notebook you can run `dbutils.notebook.exit()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I agree, the auto-termination is already in 45 mins but there are many users and it is usual the case that is something running so sometimes it will be for days without any restart. 
I guess it will be a nice feature for databricks to add in the future.